# aws lambda function invoking another lambda function not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

i an trying to invoke lambda function from another lambda function but still not able to invoke I also gave all permission required but still response body in null share Screenshot.
please tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never post images of code

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `InvocationType` to `DryRun`. `DryRun` only validates the parameter values and permissions but it does not invoke the function. If you want to invoke the function, you should put `InvocationType` to `Event` (asynchronous) or `RequestResponse` (synchronous).

You can check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)